# Push specific object into list using id React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arraylist, javascript-objects, push

I got a list of objects which im displaying on the screen with the help of .map function.
It looks like this:

Component 1:

```
let itemList = [
        {
            type: "White T-shirt",
            id: 1,
            cost: 300,
            image: whiteTshirt
        },
        {
            type: "Purple T-shirt",
            id: 2,
            cost: 350,
            image: purpleTshirt
        },
        {
            type: "Baseballcap",
            id: 3,
            cost: 150,
            image: whiteCap
        },
            {
            type: "Vice Golfball",
            id: 4,
            cost: 40,
            image: golfball
        },
        {
            type: "Mousepad",
            id: 5,
            cost: 200,
            image: mousepad
        }
    ];

       let products = itemList.map(items => {

           let item = 
           <div key={items.id}>
                <h2>{items.type}</h2>
                <img className="image"  src={items.image}></img>
                <p className="price">${items.cost}</p>
                <button onClick={onBuy} className="buy-btn">Buy</button>
            </div>
            return item;
        })

       return(
            {shoppingcart ? <Component2 /> : null}
            <main> {products} </main>
)
```

Component 2:

```
const Comopnent2 = props => {
    const [webshop, setWebshop] = useState(false);

    return(
    <div>
        {webshop ? <Webshop /> : null }
        
<a href="/Webshop" onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); setWebshop(true)}} >
<p className="to-shop"> Back to shop</p></a>
<h2 className="shopping-header">Your Shopping Cart</h2>

        <div className="cart-container">

            // Here i want to object that i clicked display

        </div>
        )
}
```

What i want is to push one specific object to another array in another component that i have. I want to do that when i click the button which calls the onBuy funcion. How do i manage that? Thanks.

Comment: its not clear to me what exactly u want ?
u can filter the list with .filter, but I'm not sure that is what u are looking for

Comment: @adirabargil i have now updated my question :)

Answer (score 1):

First create a hook for the cart item inside component 1:

```
const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState();
```

set cartItem whenever the button is clicked and onBuy is called:

```
onBuy (id) {
  let checkoutItem = this.itemList.find(item => item.id === id)
  setCartItem(checkoutItem)
}
```

You'll be required to pass item id when you declare the button which call onBuy function.

```
       let products = itemList.map(items => {

       let item = 
       <div key={items.id}>
            <h2>{items.type}</h2>
            <img className="image"  src={items.image}></img>
            <p className="price">${items.cost}</p>
            <button onClick={onBuy(item.id)} className="buy-btn">Buy</button>
        </div>
        return item;
    })
```

To pass this selection to component 2. You can pass it as a prop in component 1:

```
return(
        {shoppingcart ? <Component2 item={cartItem} /> : null}
        <main> {products} </main>
```

In the component 2 You can display the data accordingly from props:

```
const Comopnent2 = props => {
const [webshop, setWebshop] = useState(false);

return(
<div>
    {webshop ? <Webshop /> : null }
    
    <a href="/Webshop" onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); setWebshop(true)}} >
    <p className="to-shop"> Back to shop</p></a>
    <h2 className="shopping-header">Your Shopping Cart</h2>

    <div className="cart-container">
        {prop.item.name} //whatever properties your cart item has, I have used name just for example
    </div>
    )
 }
```

Comment: @gospecomid12 I have updated my answer accordingly, you can have a look

Comment: It says that my itemList is undefined? @chindicoder

Comment: It's something wrong with this line 'let checkoutItem = this.itemList.find(item => item.id === id)'. itemList becomes undefined after that

Comment: try without this keyword. just write itemList.find(item => item,id === id) . The point is itemList array should be available in the scope of the function. I have not seen your entire code so I cannot tell you exactly how to write it but I think it should work without this keyword as you have declared it directly in the component.